# My popup form keeps flickering(Windows, Chrome)

Tags: html, flicker, angular10, vmware-clarity

My popup dialog keeps flickering, the dialog is popped in an `iframe`. The environment is as below,

```
System: Windows only
Browser: Chrome only
Frontend Framework: 
   "@angular/core": "~10.1.5",
   "@clr/angular": "^4.0.3",
   "@clr/core": "^4.0.3",
```

Short video for this issue:
https://1drv.ms/v/s!Ap72n_DJE-rduGOfzwanngXcqGjP?e=Q2SaCw

My assumption,
1.The load time looks good, so it should not be performance issue.
2.The code base is the same for my test/staging/prod env, so it should not be code related issue.
3.The issue occurs sometimes on `chrome only`, `windows only`, and only for our staging environment. It seems an env related issue.
4.I can reproduce the issue randomly, and there's no regular pattern.

BTW, the popup is our service which integrated with other services in a `iframe` way.

I need some suggestion on how to trouble shot the issue.

Thanks for any comment.

Comment: Forget to mention, the popup dialog flickers when mouse move. The UI will keep still when mouse stops moving.

Comment: Does it reproduce on computers with different types of GPUs? Are you using any ultramodern CSS features that rely heavily on GPU processing, such as WebGL, WebGPU, or any CSS `filter` properties? You said the dialog exist in an `iframe`, but does the dialog _contain_ an `iframe`? Is the iframe running in the same origin as the parent webpage? (iframes have different rendering when they cross origins - for example, a same-origin iframe can be made to appear _seamless_, like part of the parent page with a transparent or blurred background, you can't do that with cross-origin iframes).

Comment: Thanks for reply. The issue can only be reproduced on some Windows System, so it may not be caused by different GPU. i am checking if it's caused by any ultramodern CSS feature

Comment: Thanks @Dai, finally the issue was resolved by adding the following style, even still we have no root cause for it.

```css
body{
  opacity: 0;
  animation: page-fade-in .2s forwards;
}
@keyframes page-fade-in {
  0% {
    opacity: 0
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like graphics corruption to me. Check your GPU drivers are up-to-date and try running Chrome with hardware-acceleration disabled.